# Is it possible to serialize DateTimeOffset to zulu time string with Json.NET?

Tags: c#, json.net, datetimeoffset

I have a DateTimeOffset object of "05/06/2014 05:54:00 PM -04:00".

When serializing using Json.NET and ISO setting, I get "2014-05-06T17:54:00-04:00".

What I would like to have is the UTC/Zulu version of that string "2014-05-06T21:54:00Z".

However, I could not find any serializer setting to achieve this. I know for DateTime serialization, I can set DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc to have the Zulu format. However, there isn't such setting option for DateTimeOffset. Am I missing something? Or do I have to create a custom override for this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try using the `IsoDateTimeConverter` that comes with Json.Net:

```
var date = new DateTime(2014, 5, 6, 17, 24, 55, DateTimeKind.Local);
var obj = new { date = new DateTimeOffset(date) };

JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter 
{ 
    DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", 
    DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal 
});

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Output:

```
{"date":"2014-05-06T22:24:55Z"}
```

Comment: I suspected there must be a built-in way to do it, but I didn't find it... +1

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I'm not sure why Json.Net doesn't apply this converter automatically for `DateTimeOffset` like it seems to for `DateTime`, but applying it manually seems to work.  Failing that, then yeah, I would write a custom converter to do the job like you showed in your answer.

Comment: you only need the  DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal , worked for me this way, without the DateTimeFormat

Comment: It only worked for me when I included both `DateTimeFormat` and `DateTimeStyles` in the converter. What's irritating is that my DateTimeOffset is parsed from UTC, but still serializes in local time unless I do this.

Answer (score 7):

You can write a custom converter like this:

```
class UtcDateTimeOffsetConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is DateTimeOffset)
        {
            var date = (DateTimeOffset)value;
            value = date.UtcDateTime;
        }
        base.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        object value = base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
        if (value is DateTimeOffset)
        {
            var date = (DateTimeOffset)value;
            value = date.ToLocalTime();
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

And apply it on the property you want using the `JsonConverter` attribute:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(UtcDateTimeOffsetConverter))]
public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. I think I can apply this converter globally using JsonConvert.DefaultSettings. I'll have to try this out later.

Comment: @Zoomzoom, check Brian's answer too, it's simpler