# C# Newtonsoft.Json cannot parse date

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) in my project for json parsing from server.

```
public class MyObj
{
    public DateTimeOffset TimeStamp { get; set; }
    //other fields....
}
```

Then:

```
MyObj test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObj>(jObject.ToString());
```

Test:

```
"TimeStamp": "2018-05-26T04:59:40:888Z" //Could not convert string to DateTimeOffset
"TimeStamp": "2018-05-26T04:59:40:88Z"  //Could not convert string to DateTimeOffset
"TimeStamp": "2018-05-26T14:59:40:888Z" //Could not convert string to DateTimeOffset
"TimeStamp": "2018-05-26T14:59:40:88Z"  //Could not convert string to DateTimeOffset

"TimeStamp": "2018-05-26T03:29:46.777Z" //works
"TimeStamp": "2018-05-26T13:29:46.77Z"  //works
"TimeStamp": "2018-05-26T03:29:46.777Z" //works
"TimeStamp": "2018-05-26T13:29:46.77Z"  //works
```

Error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Could not convert string to DateTimeOffset: 2018-05-27T04:59:40:887Z.

I am not sure why this happens, because the date is from server.

Edit:

```
{
  "clientTimestamp": "2018-05-27T06:08:40:688Z",
  "modifiedType": "",
  "type": "TEXT",
  "messageSize": 5,
  "roomId": "689355a0-604b-11e8-ae6a-9d170520ec46",
  "messageContent": "hello"
}
```

Update I finally found the issue. It was not the server response that I was parsing. It was my own object that I parsed. The description:

```
public class TempClass
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

Does not work

```
JObject jObject = new JObject();
jObject.Add("TimeStamp", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:fffZ"));
TempClass chatMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TempClass>(jObject.ToString());
```

Works

```
JObject jObject = new JObject();
jObject.Add("TimeStamp", DateTime.Now);
TempClass chatMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TempClass>(jObject.ToString());
```

Comment: Can you use `DateTime` instead of `DateTimeOffset`  ?

Comment: @Tony I think same thing happen with DateTime. Any idea why it happens?

Comment: GIve a try with `DateTime`.  I am using it right now and it works fine with Json.Net

Comment: If you want something more complex, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23505631/194717

Comment: @Tony I appreciate your help but it still showing that error `Could not convert string to DateTime: 2018-05-27T05:49:09:714Z`

Comment: Can you add the content of jObject.ToString() to this question?

Comment: @Tony The other things are fine because it is a simple object with some strings and ints, no lists or arrays  or other objects. also it works if i remove the date field.

Comment: @Tony Newton json version is 10.0.3 if it helps.

Comment: Have you tried just parsing the string to string and then passing the string to DateTime?  Not sure why Newtonsoft isn't doing it but maybe you need to parse it manually.

Comment: This version should work fine. I use older version that this and it works. Please add the actual Json string to the question so we can help easily.

Comment: @Tony Please check added, the name that I have used earlier was for simplificatoin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your timestamp is incorrect

Instead of `2018-05-27T06:08:40:688Z` should be `2018-05-27T06:08:40.688Z` 
(the millisecond is separated by a dot `.` )

Try this

```
public class RootObject
{
    public DateTime clientTimestamp { get; set; }
    public string modifiedType { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public long messageSize { get; set; }
    public Guid roomId { get; set; }
    public string messageContent { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
MyObj test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jObject.ToString());
```

In fact

2018-05-27T06:08:40:688Z
   Could not convert string to DateTime: 2018-05-27T06:08:40.688Z

2018-05-27T06:08:40.688Z
   OK

Comment: Yes I got it. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Use DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")

Comment: I have been banging my head for a long time. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is happening because data from your server is not sent in the correct json format for the Date/Time, and you are trying to deserialize them.

Comment: No it is sending because I can see it. The problem is with the date field, but I am not able to find it out.

Comment: Add the Json content to the question so we can help.