# How to serialize DateTimeOffset value to UTC format using Newtonsoft Json

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, datetimeoffset

Is it possible to serialize the DateTimeOffset as UTC format using Newtonsoft Json?

While using the following method, DateTime is property getting serialized to UTC but DateTimeOffset is not.

I know DateTimeOffset.UtcNow will solve the issue, but the actual requirement is to convert all DateTimeOffset values to Utc format while returning dotnet 5.0 web API response.

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset,
            DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat
        };

        var datetimelocalNow = DateTime.Now;
        var datetimeoffsetlocalNow = DateTimeOffset.Now;

        var datetimestring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datetimelocalNow, settings);
        var datetimeoffsetstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datetimeoffsetlocalNow, settings);


        Console.WriteLine(datetimestring);
        Console.WriteLine(datetimeoffsetstring);
```

Comment: Is this what you want?  [Json.Net, how to serialize DateTimeOffset with 'Z' instead of +00:00, but keep other timezone offsets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59276193/3744182).

Comment: Or maybe [Is it possible to serialize DateTimeOffset to zulu time string with Json.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23505294/3744182)?